# trocar o elemento quando o mesmo atingir o topo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando fazer este código para trocar o elemento quando o mesmo  atingir o topo, o elemento ficara fixo ate que o próximo atinja o top.

**HTML**

```
  <p>
  elemento A  
  </p>

 <p>
  elemento B  
 </p>

 <p>
  elemento C  
 </p>
```

**JS**

```
function scroll() {
    (window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top) {
            $('p').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0');

        } else {
            $('p').css('position', 'static');


        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível fazer um loop pelos elementos verificando qual está no topo e aplicar `fixed`, e os que não estiverem, aplicar `static`:

```js
curr_fixed = 0;
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
 els = $("p");
    janela_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
 $.each(els, function(i,v){
  if( ($(this).offset().top)-janela_scroll <= $(this).outerHeight() ){
   curr_fixed = i;
   $(this).css({
    "position":"fixed",
    "top":"0px"
   });
   
   $.each(els, function(i,v){
    if(i != curr_fixed){
     $(this).css({
      "position":"static",
      "top":"0px"
     });
    }
   });
  }
 });
});
```

```css
html, body{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
 elemento A  
</p>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<p>
 elemento B  
</p>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<p>
 elemento C  
</p>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```